# How to show only mySQL records where a certain name appears in more than X rows?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with customer information. In the table, I have:

"fullname"
"emails"
etc.

Some customers have made more than 1 order with me, so there's a row for every order and obviously also duplicate names for each order.

How can I get the mySQL records for customers that have made more than 5 orders, for example?

So that it would only show mySQL records where the "fullname" of "Michael Dell" for example shows up in >5 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick?

```
SELECT `fullname`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM tablename WHERE `count` > 5 GROUP BY `fullname`
```

Or

```
SELECT `fullname`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM tablename GROUP BY `fullname` HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Tough without details of your schema, but this is the basic idea.

```
select fullname from order group by fullname having count(*) > 5
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SELECT `fullname`, COUNT(fullname) AS `count` FROM tablename WHERE `count` > 5 GROUP BY  GROUP BY `fullname`
```